# I have created an empty file in linux and added a character to it. But it is showing up as a 2 bytes file

Tags: linux, unix

It seems it is appending a (char)10 to the end of the file. Note that I am doing this in Nautilus, not programmatically. Why does this happen? How to prevent it?

Comment: If by nautilus (which, AFAIK, doesn't edit files) you mean gedit, it does add a newline - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gedit/+bug/379367

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ASCII 0x0A is the newline '\n'.

If that file of yours has been created with `echo 1 >file` there's a newline added to it. If you're looking to skip that behavior, do `echo -n 1 >file`.

Comment: I know it is. But isn't there a way a way to prevent this behaviour?

Comment: @devoured: you probably pressed enter after entering the character:)

Answer (score 1):

The ASCII character with the decimal code 10  (0x0a in hex) is '\n' i.e. the new line (LF - Line Feed) character in Unix-like systems. How did you create the file?

EDIT:

If you use echo, you should probably try the `-n` flag which suppresses the final newline that is emitted by default:

```
echo -n X > file
```